# I need help writing a query that shows the amount of orders for each month of the year and also the cumulative amount each year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am so close to answering this question, but can't figure out the final bits.
I am using the **AdventureWorks2019** database.

My code is:

```sql
with cte as
( 
   Select 
   year(orderdate) as "Years",
   month(orderdate) as "Months",
   sum(SubTotal) as "MonthlySales", 
   datepart(m, orderdate) as "MonthNumber" 
   from sales.SalesOrderHeader 
   group by year(orderdate), month(orderdate)
) 
select 
Years, Months, MonthlySales as "MonthlySales", sum(MonthlySales) over (partition by months order by MonthlySales
                                                                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as "Cumulative"
from cte  
group by Years, Months, MonthlySales
ORDER by Years, Months
```

I cant figure out how to order the 'over' part of the query. I know it needs to be "rows between unbounded preceding and current row", but because MonthlySales is sum(totaldue), adding it to another SUM() probably messes it up.

Honestly this question is pretty tough, and I gave it my best.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try partitioning by the year and ordering by the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check and it'll return desired output.

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT t.OrderYear
     , CASE WHEN t.OrderMonth IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total' ELSE CAST(t.OrderMonth AS VARCHAR(20)) END b
     , t.MonthlySales
     , MAX(t.cum_total) cum_total
FROM (SELECT
    YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
    MONTH(OrderDate) AS OrderMonth,
    SUM(SubTotal) AS MonthlySales,
    SUM(SUM(SubTotal)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) cum_total
    
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)))) t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((t.OrderYear
     , t.OrderMonth
     , t.MonthlySales), t.OrderYear);
```

Also Check data from https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=e6cd2ba8114bd1d86b8c61b1453cafcf

Comment: Hey this kind of late, but can you explain why we need to use grouping sets twice?

Comment: Hi @Ajsrise first grouping sets is used for calculating sum and running total for year and month combinedly. then second one is used for year wise sum and also grand total text is placed in month column so this grouping sets is worked for capturing your desired output,

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function directly in the aggregation:

```
Select year(orderdate) as Years, month(orderdate) as Months,
       sum(SubTotal) as MonthlySales, 
       case when grouping(month(orderdate)) = 0
          then sum(case when month(orderdate) is not null then sum(SubTotal) end) over (partition by year(orderdate) order bymonth(orderdate))
          end as YTD_MonthlySales
from sales.SalesOrderHeader 
group by grouping sets (
  (year(orderdate), month(orderdate)),
  (year(orderdate))
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is simpler and more accurate than mine haha. If you know, can you give me a hint on how to solve the 2nd issue? Like, don't tell me how, but maybe what to use?

Comment: @Ajsrise `grouping sets` will do that for you, as Gordon has shown

Comment: @Gordon I seem to have made a tiny mistake, 'TotalDue' needs to be 'SubTotal'

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah I just noticed he edited his response. I am currently working on it as well with no success so far

Comment: @Gordon just realized the answer has the total at the top, which kinda screws up the YTD_MonthlySales column because it adds the total for the year as it goes down

Comment: @Ajsrise . . . It seems silly to me that window functions are processed *after* the `grouping sets`.  In any case, I fixed this with a `case` expression to ignore `NULL` months.